# allow duplicate entries for all posts in php

Tags: php, html, radio-button, controls

How do i allow duplicate entries in my php file from this file ... i have the html file which is a form to track radios for a company. I have text boxes and radio buttons and all the fields need to be able to have duplicate entries except for the serial number field. i keep getting and error saying i cannot have duplicate entries.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","Jason","");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO test (
        firstname,
        lastname, 
        department,
        radiomodel,
        serialnumber,
        issuedate
    )
    VALUES(
        '$_POST[firstname]',
        '$_POST[lastname]',
        '$_POST[department]',
        '$_POST[radiomodel]',
        '$_POST[serialnumber]',
        '$_POST[issuedate]'
     )";

     if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     {
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     echo "1 record added";

     mysql_close($con);
     header( "refresh:150;url=testinput.php" );
?>
```

Comment: We need to see your database structure, it is more than likely that you have some sort of unique key on a field that you are duplicating.

Comment: Do you mean my phpmyadmin screen?

Comment: put your table structure here

Comment: Don't use mysql_* use mysqli* or PDO instead

Comment: it wont let me add a screenshot

Comment: use this to share screen shot [on this link](http://tinygrab.com/)

Comment: In php myadmin goto the SQL tab then type `describe test` click go, then tell us any fields that have a key associated with them and tell us what key type it is.

Comment: http://tardis1.tinygrab.com/grabs/907c24281a2066a311768253919c8d82a075d2d54f.jpg

Comment: UPDATE `test` SET `firstname`=[value-1],`lastname`=[value-2],`department`=[value-3],`radiomodel`=[value-4],`serialnumber`=[value-5],`issuedate`=[value-6] WHERE 1

Comment: that is all it says when i enter that

Comment: Your screen grab - can you click on the "+ Indexes" (Small link, about 3/4 of the way down the page) and show that. That's the critical part. You probably have a "unique" index and the index needs to not be unique - change type to "index" by editing it.

Comment: Can you please make some var_dump($sql), to check the executed request ?

Comment: @Robbie - Hey that was it ...i had a bunch of indexes on there so i removed them ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your serialnumber is a primary key and thus you can not have duplicate values.

You should remove the primary key from the serialnumber field and add in a new id column to put the primary key on this or use multiple columns together as the key, for example use firstname, lastname and date and serialnumber as the key.

Really you should split this off into multiple tables though.

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't `I have text boxes and radio buttons and all the fields need to be able to have duplicate entries except for the serial number field.` mean his serial number field is always unique?

Comment: @t.thielemans ha very true, however if he is receiving a duplicate entry warning then the only way this would be possible is if he is entering the same serial number, since this is the only key in his table?  Or am I mistaken?